# Programmatically determining shell profile file

Tags: bash, zsh, profile

My script needs to inject an alias into shell profile file. That script may be run in bash (so it would inject the alias into ~/.bashrc) or zshell (~/.zshrc) or any other shell. Is there a way to get the name of the `rc` file for the current shell inside the script?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You'll have to test from which shell your script is being called and then write separate code for each shell.